# Is it possible to notify multiple resources to start a process?

Tags: blueprism

Suppose I have a process Load Queue (process X) that fills the Work Queue with elements that needs to be handled (Only one resource can do this). Is it possible when this process ends to signal multiple resources to start another process for processing the workqueue? Like if process X ends for each available resource start process Y on it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is scheduling *Tasks* as part of a larger *Schedule*. What you're attempting is detailed in the **Blue Prism - Guide to the Scheduler** document, available on the Blue Prism Portal under the "Documents" tab.

The high-level process you'd have to follow (using the above guide for reference) to achieve your desired functionality would be:

1. Create a schedule for the overall Business Process your individual Blue Prism Processes are associated with, scheduling the recurrence of the Schedule as required.
2. Create a task for the Load Queue process, and assign the process to the single resource you want to run the process itself. Set the Schedule to launch this Task first.
3. Create another task for the Main Process, and assign the process to all the resources you'd like to have run the queue processing functionality you've developed. Set this Task to run "On Complete" in the Load Queue task.
4. Enable the Schedule, or right-click the Schedule and select the "Run Now" option to see it execute.

You'll see that the first process is executed on the single resource you've selected. Only once that process has been Completed will the Schedule will then launch the processing phase on the multiple resources you've assigned it to.

Comment: Thanks was exactly what I was looking for! @esqew

Answer (score 0):

Once the process is done, you can start other processes via command lines :

```
AutomateC /run "Excel Test" /resource YourPCHostName /user admin mypwd /startp "<inputs>
    <input name='Comment' type='text' value='Hello World' /></inputs>"
```

Or via a scheduler name if you configured a schedule in Blue Prism :

```
AutomateC /user admin mypwd /startschedule [/schedule <name|...>]
```